# Jquery expanding divs by class

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with an if statement in the following code, I am trying to trigger an event if a div has a class, which is added and subtracted in a code. Is this the correct way to do this? Because it isn't working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.content_accrd').css({
        "height": "0px"
    });
    $('.content_accrd:eq(0)').addClass("open").css({
        "height": "110px"
    });
    $('.paneltop:eq(0)').css({
        "background-position": "0px 0px"
    })
    $('.paneltop').click(function() {
        **if ($(this).siblings('.content_accrd').attr('class') != "open")** {
            $(this).addClass("open").css({
                "background-position": "0px 0px"
            }).siblings('.content_accrd').animate({
                "height": "110px"
            }, 200)
        } else {
            $(this).reomveclass("open").css({
                "background-position": "0px -21px"
            }).siblings('.content_accrd').animate({
                "height": "0px"
            }, 200);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Is there a does not have class function? Cause that's what I want here

Comment: Do you want your code to loop through all siblings, testing each one individually?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function:

```
$('.paneltop').click(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings('.content_accrd').hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeclass("open").css({
            "background-position": "0px -21px"
        }).siblings('.content_accrd').animate({
            "height": "0px"
        }, 200);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("open").css({
            "background-position": "0px 0px"
        }).siblings('.content_accrd').animate({
            "height": "110px"
        }, 200)            
    }
})
```

Swapped the order to avoid having to use ! :D

removeClass was spelled wrong as well.

Comment: Thanks Richard, now the else statement doesn't seem to be working though, as the if statement fires on click, but then on a subsequent click the else statement does not fire

Comment: No sorry, it's the if statement that does not function

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
if ($(this).siblings('.content_accrd').hasClass('open'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it like this:

```
if ($(this).siblings('.content_accrd').hasClass('open')) {
    // ...
}
```

However, that leaves open the question: what is this test supposed to do? Test *any* sibling for having that class? *One specific* sibling? You should make that explicit.

Comment: @A_funs: Of course it's not working -- we don't know what exactly you are trying to do. Please read all of the answer and provide some more details.

Comment: I want it to tell which elements do not have the class 'open'

Comment: I think it wasn't working because Jon forgot a closing parenthesis. :-)

Comment: @A_funs: That doesn't make sense -- what's the `if` doing there then? Please edit the question and explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `.hasClass()` method:

```
if ($(this).siblings('.content_accrd').hasClass('open')) {
```

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/